# HTML over galeria fullsreen

Tags: jquery, galleria

I'm trying to customize the Galleria jQuery by putting some HTML over galleria fullscreen. This is what I got till now.

HTML:

```
<div id="logo">
    <a href="/"><img src="logo.png"></a>
    <h2>Slogan.</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo { position:absolute; left: 20px; top: 40px; z-index: 5; }
```

A working example can be seen here: http://namourphoto.com

However, the image disappears after the load of the first images. I guess it is because they are using something in JQuery that makes the images to be load on top of the last top image... So I'd have to "bind" the layer somehow.

The problem is that the html appears at the start but the disappears as the images load.

Thanks.

Comment: does this not work? what issue are you seeing? We need more context.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```css
#galleria { 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**so ...?**

```
<body onClick="document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();">
```

Now, Thats FullScreen.